# add field to opportunity?

Tags: opportunity, configuration

Describe the steps you would use in Salesforce to add a new field to the Opportunity object called Anniversary Date and set that field to a value exactly one year in the future from the Close Date.

Comment: Downvoted because while the question is clear, it doesn't show any research effort. This also sounds rather like a question for one of the certification exams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit setup from the top right corner-->search for opportunities in quickfind box-->select field-->scroll down till you see new button--->hit new--->select formula-->give the label you wanted for the field-->select date in formula return type-->next-->in the formula copy `DATE(YEAR(date field you wanted to refer) + 1,MONTH(date field you wanted to refer),DAY(date field you wanted to refer))`--->next--->select the page layouts and profiles you want to give access t0-->save

But while adding a year, we should consider the leap year as well. I f you want to add 5 years to a date feb 29, it should return march 1 since, it wont be a leap year. Please refere the below link for this, https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm

Comment: thanks Anurag. Can u plz describe the steps you would use in Salesforce to create and save a pie chart of Expected Revenue for each Forecast Category for Opportunities with a Close Date in 2015.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like an exam question. If that's true, then answering it for you would defeat the purpose of the exam.

If you haven't done so already, I'd suggest going to [Salesforce Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en) to learn about how to accomplish this (and more).

For this particular question, you may find the [using formula fields trail](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/point_click_business_logic/formula_fields) particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To add a new field  you would need to go to setup -> search for Opportunity -> click on new field button from the Opportunity Custom Fields and Relations Section -> select the Data Type as `'Formula'` -> Set a name -> Set the Formula Return Type to `Date` -> In the formula text box add `CloseDate + 365`